# Cannot access class instance methods outside main method

Tags: java

I'm working through the book "Head first Java" and started chapter 12.

When I tried to create the method `changeButtonText()` I cannot access any of the class methods from `button`.

Why is this? What have I done wrong in this code?

```java
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton button = new JButton("Click Me");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().add(button);

        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
    }

    public void changeButtonText(){
        button.setText("I've been clicked");
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't defined any class instance variables, nor have you instanciated an object to use them.

Comment: @Abra This is actually exactly how the code in the book was written on page 355. Perhaps I'm to infer that I need to make these changes per automatik when I add the changeButtonText method?

Comment: Method `changeButtonText()` does not appear in the code on page 355 of the book _Head First Java_.

Comment: @Abra changeButtonText() is my name for the author's "changeIt()" on page 357. The preceding code is as it appears on page 355

Comment: @NMard Please read my answer and let me know if there's anything you want me to clarify further :) thank you.

Comment: Continue reading up to page 360. The code on that page is a proper, working example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you cannot access the variable is because of its scope (tutorial about the scope of variables: https://www.baeldung.com/java-variable-scope).

You declare the variable `JButton button` in the `main` method, therefore it is not accessible anywhere outside of it, even in a method that `main` calls itself.

To make `changeButtonText` aware that the `button` variable exists, you have to pass it as parameters of this method:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JButton button = new JButton("Click Me");

        changeButtonText(button);
    }

    public static void changeButtonText(JButton button){
        button.setText("I've been clicked");
    }
}
```

I also added the `static` keyword in front of the `changeButtonText` method, because `main` is also a static method. Check this link for example to have more details about the difference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-methods-vs-instance-methods-java/

Answer (score 2):

Surely this is a problem of scope and it can be overcome with defining variable at global level and initialize wherever you required. something like -

```
public class Main {

private static JButton button;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        button = new JButton("Click Me");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Main.changeButtonText();

    }

    public static void changeButtonText(){
        button.setText("I've been clicked");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things that is wrong with your code and concepts that you seem to not fully grasp. These concepts are `this.` and `scopes`.

```
public void changeButtonText(){
    button.setText("I've been clicked");
}
```

First we need to talk about scopes. A scope is what's declared between `{ /* here */ }` i.e. two curly brackets. From within a scope you can access and declare both local and global *objects, variables, members etc*.

So here's an example using local scope (what you did):

```
public void myFunction(){
    JButton button = new Jbutton();
}
```

If I then go ahead and try to access the button outside of the scope, it wont know what `button` is. Since it's not declared within that local scope.

```
public void myFunction(){
    JButton button = new Jbutton();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    button.setText("hello"); //error
    // compiler thinks: what's `button` referring to here? its not declared in this scope.
}
```

Global class scope:

```
JButton button = new JButton(); //declaring button in global class scope
public void myFunction(){
    this.button.setText("hello"); // will access the globally declared variable, object, member called `button`.
    //^ notice the usage of `this`. 
    //`this` will look outside of the local functions scope for publically declared class-members.
}
```

To fix your particular problem, you could either make your function static and pass in a `JButton` object, or you could *declare your button in the global class scope* like this:

```
public class Main {

    JButton button = new JButton("Click Me"); //global class scope

    public static void main(String[] args) { //local scope of main start {
        Main myClass = new Main(); //instantiate class
        myClass.changeButtonText(); //access class-member function
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().add(this.button); // this.

        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    } // local scope of main ends }

    public void changeButtonText(){
        this.button.setText("I've been clicked"); //access global class members using `this` keyword
    }

}
```